# Best python data structure for storing verb data

Tags: python, json

I have some Italian language data that I would like to store in an efficient format. There are 4 parameters: verb, mood, tense and pronoun. For any set of values for the four parameters, there is an associated conjugation. For example,

Given that verb=ABALIENARE, mood=INDICATIVO, tense=PRESENTE, pronoun=TU we have that the particular conjugation of the verb is ABALIENI

More generally, the data is formatted like so:
[VERB][MOOD][TENSE][PRONOUN] => [CONJUGATION]

Currently I am storing this data as 4 level nesting of JSON dictionaries. For example, if the data is stored in a python dictionary `D` I could access it like so:

```
print(D["ABALIENARE"]["INDICATIVO"]["PRESENTE"]["TU"])
```

This is not a particularly efficient storage method as it involves lots of repetition, so I'd like to know of a better alternative that is somewhat standard. More generally, I am interested in finding a good format for storing this kind of data.

Here is another example of a similar kind of data. Consider data regarding cars, where there are two attribute for each car, the make and year, and given a particular make and particular year, we have a retail price. This is quite similar to the Italian data, except instead of having 4 attributes like before, we now have only 2. In particular this kind of data has n attributes, and these attributes don't have any particular order, for example, there is no sense in which "make" should go before "year" in the car example, or any reason to specify some particular order for 'verb,mood,tense,pronoun'. Ideally this should be reflected in the data format, unlike in the dictionary based format I gave above.

Hopefully there is a somewhat standard way to store this kind of data. If so I'd like to know where I can read more about it. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest a *database* as a storage model. Your data is very well structured and hierarchical, and the lookups could benefit greatly from hashed indices. You could pair it with a convenient *caching* mechanism.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this however it is not clear to me whether a database would store the data more efficiently. Say I made the columns of the database VERB,MOOD,TENSE,PRONOUN,CONJUGATION. Many rows would contain the verb 'ABALIENARE' because there are many permutations of MOOD,TENSE, and PRONOUN. I don't want the database to have to store this string any more times than necessary. I could give each VERB,MOOD,TENSE, and PRONOUN a number which would save space, but this would make the database more complex.